# Ubuntu14.04 does not shutdown and reboot

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a VM and at the end of the installation, the screen says a reboot is necessary to complete the install,,,

I clicked on reboot and the VM restarts but stops at...

> Asking all remaining process to terminate  ok.

No errors are shown.

Is the install completed ?

Can I just hard restart the VM?

Answer (score 0):

I think so. Probably you only were asked to reboot to make your system use a newly installed kernel.

But if that happens always (ie you try to reboot your VM and it just hangs) you may want to check your VM settings and check if ACPI is enabled in your guest OS.

Comment: That seemed to work,,,,,I can now login, but using the Desktop User Accounts interface, I can add a user but there is no option to set the user password ?

Comment: You can set the password after you created the account, clicking in "Password"